# How to generate filename from message in NLog

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, nlog

I'm using NLog 5.2.4
My messages looks like this:

> [127.0.0.1:50543]: Here comes some text ....
> [127.0.0.1:50544]: Here comes some text ....

I want messages to be logged to files with name
test_127.0.0.1_50543.log
test_127.0.0.1_50544.log
and so on.

One of my attempts looked something like this:

```
<target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" name="testAsync" queueLimit="50000" timeToSleepBetweenBatches="0" batchSize="500" overflowAction="Grow">
      <target name="testFile"
              layout="${longdate} ${level:uppercase=true} ${logger} ${message} ${exception:format=ToString:innerFormat=ToString:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5}"
              fileName="Log/test_${replace:regex=true:searchFor=^\\[(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\:\\d+)\\].*:replaceWith=\$1:input=${message}}.log"
              xsi:type="File"
              maxArchiveFiles="5"
              archiveAboveSize="10000000"
      />
    </target>
```

so far I get whole message in filename or nothing.

I have multiple objects and all of them have same ILogger.
Maybe I can add somehow custom attribute/variable/property in object for NLog to use?

Comment: Instead of using RegEx then consider using `logger.WithProperty("RequestUrl", requestUrl).Info("Here comes some text...")`. Then you can use `fileName="Log/test_${event-properties:RequestUrl:whenEmpty=App}.log"`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer and https://nlog-project.org/config/?tab=layout-renderers

Comment: Thank you very much. I was able to do it with ${event-properties:item=RemoteEndPoint}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the [@rolf-kristensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/193178/rolf-kristensen) I was able to do it with

```
fileName="logs/test_${event-properties:item=RemoteEndPoint}.log"
```

in NLog.config

And in the code I have

```
Logger.LogTrace("[{RemoteEndPoint}]: startValue: {startValue}", RemoteEndPoint, startValue);
```